# Experience taking iMac on plane as carry-on

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I will be flying from Halifax to Calgary (for any non-Canadians, its about 4500km, 5 hour flight) a couple weeks from now, and need to bring my new iMac with me.  The reason I say 'new' iMac is because the current model is smaller and lighter than previous ones.  The official size and weight from the Apple site are:

> Height: 17.7 inches (45.0 cm)
>
> Width: 20.8 inches (52.8 cm)
>
> Stand depth: 6.9 inches (17.5 cm)
>
> Weight: 12.5 pounds (5.68 kg)

I am hoping that I will be able to take it as carry on, because I really don't want to check it with the rest of the luggage.

My question is:  does anyone have experience taking their iMac with them on a plane?  If so, could you take it as carry-on?

---

Here are the specs: http://www.apple.com/imac/specs/

Note that this is different to the existing question on [Taking a Desktop PC as a Carry-On](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18794/taking-a-desktop-pc-as-carryon), because an iMac is a different shape and has an integrated screen.

Comment: Have you considered simply shipping it?

Comment: Not really.  I figured since I was going to be flying I would just take the computer on with me, especially if I can just put it in the overhead bin.

Comment: iMac and Desktops are physically totally different, a normal desktop has a screen and a tower or desktop case, iMac it is an all-in-one device, which basically means it is a screen only. This question can not be duplicate to the other question. Voted to re-open.

Comment: What works for a "classical" desktop will work for an iMac too. Hence a duplicate.

Comment: I disagree that an iMac is different from a PC. There are PCs with integrated screens too, and I don't see how functionally the answer can be different. The primary concern when transporting would be the screen I'd guess, which is the same regardless whether it's integrated or not.

Comment: Removing the hard drive, as suggested in an anwser of the other question, is far from trivial on an iMac. If this question is a duplicate, it is one of general questions on carry-on luggage: An iMac doesn't pass dimension limit of most airlines.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its an iMac, an integrated desktop, a hybrid or whatever - the only two questions you need to answer [a] do you have the original packaging? [b] does the device **once packed in its original packaging** violate the on-board luggage restrictions for the airline you are flying. Everything else (like "removing the hard drive") is immaterial. If your answer for the two questions is yes, then you can take it with you as a carryon.