# PC suitcase carry on

Tags: hand-luggage

Im planning to put suitcase wheels and a retractable handle onto my pc and roll it in as a carry on onto the plane with a front glass panel and its under the weight limit and size?

Comment: Would you mind sharing an image with us? 

Comment: What PC do you have? Some "ancient" *Big Tower*?

Comment: You really ought to ask over on serverfault whether this is a good idea.  (It's not, for durability reasons.) Is there any possible way you can get the job done with a Mac Mini?  That's *literally made for this problem*.   (or <del>comparable</del> similar-sized PC mini-cases).

Comment: I'd say that this is actually a duplicate of [Is it possible to take a desktop PC as carry-on luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18794/is-it-possible-to-take-a-desktop-pc-as-carry-on-luggage).

Answer (score 2):

No, because of a structural issue.  **PC cases are not made for the dynamic forces they would encounter being rolled around**.  It would twist and crack the PC case to the point of falling apart.  Honestly, CostCo-tier luggage can barely handle it, and it's made to be luggage!

Besides, *even if you were exceptionally careful* the vibration (rollers) and shock (bumps)  would still unseat boards and connections.  Every card slot would at risk of popping out. I've had that happen simply from customers bringing their PC into the service department, that's why when someone rents 40 PCs I sent 43. Reseating boards is one of the first things you do when opening up a case on the service bench.  I could also see heat sinks being torn off, CPUs unseated, and other adventures.  *Those clips are simply not made for *these* dynamic forces.  Look at aviation grade computers for instance - very different.

I actually do have a "travel with desktop PC" requirement, so I've given it a lot of thought.  For a PC to endure such treatment, I'd want an all-soldered PC - video card part of the motherboard and soldered down, SSD drive (certainly not HD) also soldered, and RAM either soldered or with really good clips.  At that point we're talking about a PC that is a single board; it'd be so small *you'd wrap it in a couple sweaters and toss it in your carry-on*.

The Mac Mini comes to mind.